# error while installing snmp package in SUSE 11

Tags: snmp, suse

I am trying to install SNMP package in SUSE Linux enterprise server 11. I downloaded net-snmp-5.6.1-3.3.x86_64.rpm and installed with the below command

```
UKGBDCESRPL048:/opt/packages # rpm -ivh --nodeps net-snmp-5.6.1-3.3.x86_64.rpm
```

> warning: net-snmp-5.6.1-3.3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 3dbdc284
>   Preparing...
>
> ##################################### [100%]
>
> 1:net-snmp
>
> ##################################### [100%]
>
> Updating /etc/sysconfig/net-snmp...

But when I try to start snmpd service, I am getting an error below:

> UKGBDCESRPL048:/opt/packages # /etc/init.d/snmpd start
>       Starting snmpd/usr/sbin/snmpd: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>       startproc:  exit status of parent of /usr/sbin/snmpd: 127

Please help me to properly install SNMP package.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to install the RPM with `--nodeps`? This breaks your RPM dependencies! Please remove the package again and try to install it without that option. This should fail with a list of additionally required RPM's.

You'll have to install them, too. BTW, I'm sure that at least the RPM `libsnmp15` is missing, because libnetsnmpagent.so.25 is in there.

You could also configure SLES to use one or more (online) repositories after registering your machine with a license key. After that, a simple

```
zypper in net-snmp
```

should solve all dependencies automatically.

One more thing: `net-snmp-5.6.1-3.3.x86_64.rpm` doesn't seem to be a valid SLES 11 package. Latest version (even SP4) is 5.4.2.1-8.12.24.1. Where did you get the RPM from? Just wondering...